# How to pass multiple variables in grep

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, centos

I have a json file that is download using curl. It has some information of a confluence page. I want to extract only 3 parts that downloaded information - that is page: **id, status and title**.
I have written a bash script for this and my constraint is that I am not sure how to **pass multiple variables in grep command**

```
id=id         #hardcoded 
status=status    #hardcoded

echo Enter title you are looking for: #taking input from user here read title_name echo echo echo Here are details

curl -u username:password -sX GET "http://X.X.X.X:8090/rest/api/content?type=page&start=0&limit=200" | python -mjson.tool | grep -Eai "$title_name"|$id|$status"
```

Comment: Use one set of double-quotes around the whole argument: `grep -Eai "$title_name|$id|$status"`. But actually, I'd recommend parsing JSON with something that actually understands it, like `jq`, instead of kluging it with `grep`. (Unless `json.tool` converts it to flat data or something?)

Comment: Use jq not bash.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a typo (you have an unbalanced quote - please always check the syntax for correctness before you are posting something), the basic idea of your approach would work in that

```
grep -Eai "$title_name|$id|$status"
```

would select those text lines which contain those lines which contain the content of one of the variables `title_name`, `id` or `status`.

However, it is a pretty fragile solution. I don't know what can be the actual content of those variables, but for instance, if `title_name` were set to `X.Z`, it would also match lines containing the string *XYZ*, since the dot matches any character. Similarily, if `title_name` would contain, say, a lone `[` or `(`, *grep* would complained about an *unmatched parentheses* error.

If you want to match the string **literally** and not be taken as regular expressions, it is better to write those pattern into a file (one pattern per line) and use

```
grep -F -f patternfile
```

for searching. Of course, since you are using bash, you can also use [process substitution](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection) if you prefer not using an explicit temporary file.